# Reading a Text file from Path beginning with /// and containing a colon

Tags: java, tomcat, path

I am, as stated in the headline, trying to read a file from a path given to me as a String, located in a Tomcat-Context file.

The path starts with "///C:". On Unix systems it would start with "/C:".
As of now I am trying to do as follows:

```
MyPath = Paths.get("///C:" + filename);
byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(MyPath);
String JsonString = new String(encoded);
```

this leads to this error: "Illegal character [:] in path at index 4: ///C:/file.json"

I know Windows doesnt like Colons in its Paths, but when I cut the leading Substirng "///" from the Path, windows can handle it. (But that doesn't realy help me, since this is fragile and a realy bad way of coding. Also it doesn't work on half of the servers)

I am pretty shure this is just me not understanding the path-naming-convention.
So in what way should this kind of paths be handled?

Greetings:
Junge

Comment: You should also keep in mind that not everyone uses C: (some people have like D:)

Comment: the leading "///C:/" is not realy a static string. I just replaced it with one for the question, so its easier to read. 
In reality this will be set by the context of the server. But thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was, that I did not treat the URL I received as an URL.
The following code snippet did the trick:

`MyPath = Paths.get( new URL("///C:" + filename).toURI() );`

It works on both systems. I think Paths.get() understands the "///" only in URLs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to check the OS you're on first with System.getProperty() (as a constant would be more efficient IMO, but depending on your program) :

```
private static final boolean Windows = System.getProperty( "os.name" ).contains( "indow" );
```

It will be true if you are on Windows and false for the other (Linux/OS X)

You then have to check if you are on Windows the moment you pass your file path. If it's true a substring() is necessary (*e.g:* passing "C:" instead of "///C:"), else give it as it is for other OS :

```
MyPath = Paths.get((Window ? drive.substring(3) : drive) + filename);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you.

Maybe this works, I recently found out, that if you get a URL, you should treat is as one and not as a simple String.

The following code snippet did the trick:
`MyPath = Paths.get( new URL("///C:" + filename).toURI() );`
It works on both systems.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know ! You can put that as an answer btw.